# Google Groups holding legitimate email from subscribers as spam

Tags: spam-prevention, google-groups

I'm an admin using a free version of Google Groups as an email list.

Lately, Google Groups has been holding a lot of legitimate emails from subscribed users as spam.   Worse, it hasn't been informing me of this quickly so I can approve those messages in a timely manner.

I've found a Google Groups for Businesses, but not for free users like myself. Is there such a help forum?

Is there anything I can do to get Google to not sequester my users' email as spam?

Comment: Do the subjects and contents of those held emails contain any triggers for the Google spam filter? The spam filter works based on the content also, including the known emails.

Comment: That is what I would like to know.  The email look innocent enough to me.  Nothing about remedies for high mortgage rates, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Steve, according to [this post](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/2zMbx5Y8WFg/ls0Otuf6szgJ) from 2012, Google doesn't allow you to disable spam moderation in free Google Groups. You can disable it in Google Groups for Business by following [these directions](https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/google-migration-project-site/how-to/manage-a-google-group#TOC-Managing-Spam), although I know that doesn't directly help you in this situation.

I assume that you are getting an email from Google around 3 days after the "spam" mail is caught by the filter (that was the time window I observed). Does the email contain a link where you can view the moderation queue in its entirety (it does on Google Apps for Business)? If so, you can manually check that page daily to make sure nothing gets caught for more than 24 hours.

Your second option is to drop the ~$60/year on Google Apps ($8-12 for domain, $50 for one user/year) and set up the group that way. You can create an administrator user to manage the domain and then create an unlimited number of groups (no increase in licensing costs).

Comment: I was guessing that was the situation.  Thanks for the confirmation.  I set up an email reminder for myself to check that folder once a day.

Comment: I think you can whitelist users - see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106559/whitelist-email-address-for-a-google-group
See also https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123271/204168