# Whitelist email address for a Google Group

Tags: email, google-groups

We are a [free and open source software project](https://www.cryptopp.com/). We set-up [a Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cryptopp-build) for build results from services like Travis, AppVeyor, CodeFresh and Coverity. The list *does not* allow *Public* to post since we want to avoid all the viagra, penis enlargement, religious and other useless posts that flood a list.

We are trying to configure a whitelist for the group because sender email addresses, like `builds@travis-ci.org` and `no-reply@appveyor.com`, are not monitored.  There's no one to interact with an invitation or a challenge system.

I found the ***Manage*** link, but I cannot figure out how to add the desired email addresses so the services can post to the list. Searching is not turning up much information, either. I'm guessing I have not used the correct keywords.

How do we whitelist the addresses so the build services can post to the group?

Answer (score 4):

This is a frustrating limitation in Google Groups. There is no explicit whitelist. Only once a user has a post marked as spam, inevitable because of the awful false positive rate and no ability to disable spam filtering, you can then whitelist the user. Visit the group and select pending messages and click the button shown in the screenshot below.

Adding insult to injury, it often isn't even until the next day that moderators receive the spam email notification.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And this doesn't always work.  We have a vendor that usually ends up here and we choose to accept all future emails and the next time it marks it as spam.  And we don't get the message for almost two days to know it was flagged.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested on my configuration and what I had to do is enable addition of external members and then add an external email address with posting permissions, but not receive any emails.

In group settings, you have to enable the following settings:
[image]

Not sure about you, but I am using Google Workspace Enterprise version to manage our domain groups.

Example screenshot below:
[image: group-test]